# Convert Rows To Columns Json

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have the following two row in a column.

```
{"backendAddr":"1.1.2.3:22","backendConnectTime":"HAHA"}
{"backendAddr":"3.3.5.6:22","backendConnectTime":"HEHE"}
```

I want to split the data in a row into multiple columns.
For Example:

```
backendAddr   backendConnectTime
1.1.2.3:22    HAHA
3.3.5.6:22    HEHE
```

If it Helps, I am actually converting json file into a column format without creating external table and running as following

```
SELECT *
      FROM JSON_TABLE (
              BFILENAME ('DIR_NAME',
                         'file.json'),
              '$[*]'
              COLUMNS (BIG_COL VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'))
```

Comment: `columns( backendAddr varchar2(100) path '$.backendAddr', backendConnectTime varchar2(100) path '$.backendConnectTime')`

Comment: It did not show any rows. Blank only.

Comment: The comment given by @astentx worked for me on 12c given an array of _funny_  json objects.
SELECT *
  FROM
    JSON_TABLE ( '[ {"backendAddr":"1.1.2.3:22","backendConnectTime":"HAHA"}
                   ,{"backendAddr":"3.3.5.6:22","backendConnectTime":"HEHE"}
                  ]'
    ,'$[*]'
        COLUMNS (
            big_col VARCHAR2 ( 4000 CHAR ) FORMAT JSON PATH '$'
        ,backendaddr VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.backendAddr'
        ,backendconnecttime VARCHAR2 ( 100 ) PATH '$.backendConnectTime'
        )
    )